# I don't like money but something similar - What am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Looking for me?  Here I am:

```
If you youtube essentials for living
If you have been rude to my brothers and sisters
If you describe ecosystem in a lesson
If you have been to Beetle's music concert, twice.
If you bribe eminem.
```

What am I?

Comment: is it tangible like 'money' or intangible like 'passion' ?

Comment: @WeShall it is tangible definitely

Comment: Is Beetle's on purpose or do you mean Beatles' ?

Comment: @hexomino as you've described in your answer, Beetle's on purpose

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer seems to be

> Bee

Because

> Each line conspicuously contains the letters of **bee** consecutively and each line describes some aspect of bees.

Highlighting

> If you youtu**be e**ssentials for living. 
>  If you have **bee**n rude to my brothers and sisters. 
>  If you descri**be e**cosystem in a lesson 
>  If you have **bee**n to **Bee**tle's music concert, twice. 
>  If you bri**be e**minem.

Further explanations

> A bees role in pollination is essential to sustain life (at least human life) on Earth. 
>  Being rude to my brothers and sisters could refer to expressions such as *'mind your own beeswax'* or *'buzz off'*. 
>  Bees are an essential part of our ecosystem so would certainly see a mention in a lesson about the ecosystem. 
>  The *twice* at the end of the 4th line refers to the fact that **bee** appears twice in the sentence. The misspelling of 'Beatles' may be intentional as a joke to suggest that a bees favourite band is the 'Beetles'. 
>  Eminem has featured on a song called 'Sweet Honey Bee'.

I don't like money but something similar - What am I?

> Honey is similar to money, in spelling, at least.

Comment: You got all of them correct!  Nicely done!